# Quotient of Polynomial Ring is Artinian

Tags: commutative-algebra

I start with the polynomial ring $R = \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and the ideal $I=(x^2 + ax, y^2 + by, xy + bx, xy +ay)$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{C}^*$, $a\neq b$.
I would like to prove that $R/I$ is artinian. I know that that $R$ and thus $R/I$ are noetherian, so I am left to show that $\dim(R/I)=0$.

Any ideas on how this can be done (rather elementarily)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even easier than doing "Noetherian + $0$ dimensional":

$R/I$ is spanned as a $\mathbb C$ vector space by the set $\{1+I, x+I, y+I\}$, so it is a finite dimensional $\mathbb C$ algebra, hence Artinian.

Comment: How does one prove that  $\{1+I,x+I,y+I\}$ is a basis, in fact, isn't $\{1+I,x+I\}$ already a basis?

Comment: @EinStone It is, but I didn’t want to waste time proving anything was a basis.  Since it is a generating set, that’s already enough, and it’s easy to see it is a generating set.

Answer (score 1):

Find all the solutions! If it is finite, then the ring has dimension 0.

Comment: Why does finitely many solutions imply dim = 0?